# Exchange 2007 - GetUserAvailability over 128 mailboxes?

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

When making a GetUserAvailability call passing in 128 mailboxs Exchange 07 returns an EmailAddressArray error stating the allowed size of the array is 100.

Is there a way to increase the array size beyond 100, so that Exchange 07 returns with a GetUserAvailablity request?

I'm currently getting the following error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.IdentityArrayTooBigException: There are too many target users in the EmailAddress array. The allowed size = 100; the actual size = 128. ---> There are too many target users in the EmailAddress array. The allowed size = 100; the actual size = 128.
```

Comment: How about splitting it into multiple arrays, each containing 100, and joining them in the code after the Exchange calls?

Comment: We actually wound up doing something like that.  We were hoping that there was a setting or something that we could change to allow more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at this time there is no way to increase this maximum number. Sorry, Richard

*"The Availability service expands distribution lists to retrieve the free/busy status for each member of the list, as long as the number of mailboxes in the distribution list is less than 100 identities, which is the maximum number of identities that the Web service method can request."*

Source: [MSDN Library > Exchange Web Services Operations > GetUserAvailability Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa564001(EXCHG.80).aspx)